# Extra byte in TCP- vs RTMP-level packet

Tags: tcp, rtmp

I am trying to debug a RTMP client that fails to connect to some servers. I'm using Wireshark to capture the packets and compare them with a client that connects successfully (in this case, ffmpeg).

Looking at the captured packets for a successfull connection, I noticed that, when viewing at TCP level, there is an extra byte in the payload (see pics below). The extra byte has value 0xc3 and is placed at byte 0xc3 in the payload.

I Googled the best I could to find information about extra bytes in the TCP payload, but I didn't find anything like this. I tried to look in the TCP spec but no luck either. Where can I find information about this ?

TCP-level view

[image: TCP-level view]

RTMP-level view

[image: RTMP-level view]

Comment: can you find any solution, i have that problem

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the message length is larger than the maximum chunk size (as per the RTMP spec, the default maximum chunk size is 128). So if no `Set Chunk Size` control message was sent before `connect` (in your case), and the `connect` message is greater than 128 bytes, the client will split the message into multiple chunks.

0xC3 is the header of the next chunk, looking at the bits of 0xC3 we would have `11 000011`. The highest 2 bits specify the format (fmt = 3 in this case, meaning that this next chunk is a type 3 chunk as per the spec). The remaining 6 bits specify the chunk stream ID (in this case 3). So that extra byte you're seeing is the header of a new chunk. The client/server would then have to assemble these chunks to form the complete message.